# scp gives "Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password)"

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

I'm having a remote server running SSH, I use the scp from my local computer like this:
scp filename.txt username@IP:Port:home/username

it asks for the password, I supply it, he doesn't accept it for 3 times and then I get 
"Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter the correct password.

---

Also, check the system log of your server. Try connecting to a `sudo sshd -rddp 222`. Try connecting from a different PC.